# modifying select with DOM

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

I've found some results for this on google but nothing satisfying so I was hoping someone here might know.

It seems as though populating a select element using innerHTML does not work in IE

I have set up a file that does nothing but that and it works with everything but IE, here's the code in case anyone cares:

```
<html>
<head></head>

<body onload="populate();">
<script type="text/javascript">
  function populate()
  {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = '<option id="a">works</option>';
  }
</script>

<select id="test"></select>

</body>
</html>
```

Anyone know a solution to this? I don't want to remove everything and then manually use appendChild as I am returned html from a different function, and it seems ridiculous that this doesn't work.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out: [BUG: Internet Explorer Fails to Set the innerHTML Property of the Select Object](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276228)

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** This answer was written before the OP said he didn't want to use `appendChild()`. I will keep this answer up for reference.

---

This post will use POJSF. (Plain Old JavaScript Framework, the framework every other framework is based on!)
<sup>For those who don't get it, that's a poor attempt a humor...</sup>

Instead of using innerHTML, you can create your `<option>` using `document.createElement()`

```
var newOption = document.createElement('option');
newOption.label = 'works';

newOption.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newOption.label));

newOption.id = 'a';

document.getElementById('mySelect').appendChild(newOption);
```

If you want to remove all `<option>` in a `<select>`:

```
var selectEl = document.getElementById('mySelect');
for(var i = selectEl.children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    selectEl.removeChild(selectEl.children[i]);
}
```

Comment: innerText is not supported by Firefox, see http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html

Comment: **@karim79:** Thanks, fixed. InnerText is really just needed in IE6, so even if Firefox doesn't support it, it doesn't need it.

Comment: **@karim79:** Only in Quirks mode and only in edge cases. Otherwise, the `.label` property works just fine.